# android SMS doesn't send and just draft

Tags: android, android-intent, service, sms

I'd like to send SMS in some condition. Therefore, I have to do this in service. but it just drafted. How can I solve this problem?

Service.java

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   String smsBody = "test";
   intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
   intent.putExtra("address", phonenumber);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phonenumber));
   context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> set in the manifest?

Comment: @Kamil sure but it never works..

Comment: You may need to add your app as an "accessibility service" in Android, because from what I know there can only be **one** "default messaging app" and this default app is the only app that can actually send SMS messages.